# internal error occured after json decoding 1100 elements using python

Tags: python, json, python-internals

I am using python to decode an api response,which is in json format.After 1100 data checking this error occurs

```
<Response [200]>
{'error': 'internal error'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/freelancer_projects/ahref/app2.py", line 63, in <module>
    get_rating()
  File "E:/freelancer_projects/ahref/app2.py", line 46, in get_rating
    result.append((u,data["domain"]["domain_rating"]))
KeyError: 'domain'
```

As you can see the response from the api is ok,but the error just saying its internal.Why is this error and what will be its fix ? I am using requests library to get data from api

full code:

```
def get_rating():
    fr = input("Enter filename of urls:")
    token = input("Enter token:")
    f = open(fr, "r",encoding="utf8")
    urls = f.readlines()
    result=[]
    count=1
    for u in urls:
        u = u.replace("http://", "")
        u = u.replace("https://", "")
        if "www" not in u:
            u="www"+u
        ind = u.find("www")
        u = u[ind:]
        u=u.replace('\n', '')

        u=u[:-1]
        # print(u)

        data=getPageData(u,token)
        if data != "":
            print(data)
            # print(data)
            # print(data["domain"]["domain_rating"])
            result.append((u,data["domain"]["domain_rating"]))
            print(count)
            count+=1

    # print(result)
    result=sorted(result,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
    # print(result)
    saveData(result)
def saveData(result):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet =wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "URL"
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "DOMAIN RATING"
    for index,r in enumerate(result):
        sheet.cell(row=index+2, column=1).value = r[0]
        sheet.cell(row=index+2, column=2).value = r[1]
    wb.save("output.xlsx")
get_rating()
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your code:

```
result.append((u,data["domain"]["domain_rating"]))
```

You are trying to access a key in the `data` dictionary that does not exist, resulting in your error:

```
KeyError: 'domain'
```

You'd best check if the key exists in your dictionary before accessing, like this:

```
if "domain" in data:
    print('found domain')
```

On a side note, using this code

```
if data != ""
```

to check your dictionary isn't a very good idea, it will always be `True`, see this example in Python interpreter:

```
>>> mydict = dict(foo='foo', bar='bar')
>>> mydict
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
>>> mydict != ""
True
>>> mydict2 = dict()
>>> mydict2
{}
>>> mydict2 != ""
True
>>> mydict2 = None
>>> mydict2 != ""
True
```

As you can see, with an empty dict, and even if we set `mydict2` to `None`, we satisfy the condition, but your code below would fail.

Comment: ok,thanks.However it will work,but thought as the response was ok ,then something unusual just happened.Anyway thanks for the help.Much appreciated

Comment: @AlMashudShishir The thing is, your code as it is might work in some cases, and fail in others. For example, the check for `data` you use could fail if the API doesn't return data, see the edit.